# Unity error when creating project - Project path is invalid

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi trying to create a new project on a network drive in unity 5.1.3 and I keep getting the error

`project path is invalid - make sure you are not using illegal characters`

The current 'location' I am using is

`\\192.168.1.16\Code\Unity\MyGame\`

Any ideas why I am getting the error?  Is it to do with it being a network address?

I can create the project locally, move it in windows explorer to the network drive and then open it in unity, but can't seem to create it initially on the network drive.

Comment: Can you map a drive to that location, or reference it by machine name instead of IP, and then try? I'm wondering if perhaps this may be a red herring too if for some reason your account does not have adequate write permissions to that remote directory. If it still doesn't work I imagine its something to do with the initial double slashes.

Comment: Yeh I def have permission. Also In Windows 10, you can't map a drive to a letter so have to use literal addresses. Also I already  tried using machine name rather than IP with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation this seems to be a bug in unity where it doesn't like mapped network Drives.

As a side note, if you open a project on a network drive it will allow you to do it, but then makes Unity unstable when using some functionality. For example trying to import an asset pack from the asset store to a project on a networked drive will cause Unity to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue -- my network drive was showing up with the path defined - when I entered in the drive designation that the path was assigned to - (example - my network path was assigned to drive H: - using that designator worked while the network path did not.